# Randomize map in C++

Tags: c++

I was looking for a way to randomize an `std::map<unsigned int,double>` in a way that keeps keys and values together but mixes elements. Do you have a good suggestion? I found that `std::random_shuffle` doesn't work for maps. Shuffling the values in a vector format is not helpful in my case. Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: `map` is ordered by definition, you *can't* shuffle it. You can't set the order of elements in `unordered_map` either. Your only choice is to use a container that has ordering, such as `vector`.

Comment: a std::map has its keys sorted as part of the definition "std::map is a *sorted* associative container" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::map`  is **a sorted associative container**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), therefore it doesn't support arbitrary re-arrangement of key-value pairs.

Assuming that you need the map to associate key and values, you can use an auxiliary `std::vector` of pointers to the map elements in order to define a different iteration sequence:

```
using pair_type = std::pair<unsigned int, double>;
std::vector<const pair_type*> pair_ptrs;

for(const auto& p : your_map) 
{
    pair_ptrs.emplace_back(&p);
}

std::shuffle(std::begin(pair_ptrs), std::end(pair_ptrs), /* ... */);
```

*(Note that [`std::random_shuffle` is deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). You should use `std::shuffle` instead.)*

Comment: Thank, you, that's an interesting approach. In the next step, I would run a for-loop over the map, `for (auto it = ++areas.begin(); it != areas.end(); it++) {}`. How would I rephrase it when using the pointer?

Comment: Or can I simply use `while (pair_ptrs++){}` ?

Comment: You would iterate over the pointer vector itself: `for(const auto& ptr : pair_ptrs){ do_something(*ptr); }`.

Comment: Just a few typos in your answer where you wrote `pair_pts` instead of `pair_ptrs`

Comment: @fitzy_blarb: `if(ptr->second > MAXVALUE)` should work. Fixed the typos, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known. I also had to replace `std::vector<const pair_type *> pair_ptrs;` by `std::vector<pair_type *> pair_ptrs;`, `for(const auto& ptr : pair_ptrs)` by `for(auto& ptr : pair_ptrs)` and `for(const auto& p : your_map) ` by `for(auto& p : your_map) `, otherwise I get `error: cannot convert ‘std::pair<const unsigned int, double>*’ to ‘std::pair<unsigned int, double>*’ in initialization`

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to shuffle a `std::map` since that particular container stores the elements in an order specified by its comparator. A `std::unordered_map` cannot (easily) be used either, since that stores its elements according to a hashing function.

Your best bet is to use a `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int,double>>`. You can shuffle that using `std::shuffle`.